# IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI when trying to copy a file from the app directory to somewhere else

Tags: android, uri, inputstream, outputstream, storage-access-framework

When trying to copy a file from the apps directory to another place in the internal storage i get following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3Aitubego/Lohn.docx
```

My code:

```
destinationLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree(), result -> {

                try {
                    String selectedFileName = arrayList.get(fileIndex);

                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(result.toString()).buildUpon().appendPath(selectedFileName).build();

                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(resAdapter.getSelectedFileToExport() + selectedFileName);

                    OutputStream outputStream = requireActivity().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);

                    IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, outputStream);

                }catch (Exception ioException){
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(), ioException.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });
```